# SQL Filter Out Specific Month, Day, and Time for Any Year

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, dynamics-nav

`Microsoft Dynamics NAV` uses the `datetime` of `yyyy-12-31 23:59:59.000` to identify yearly closing entries.  I am trying to write a report that will bring all of my entries, except for these.  The query works fine for `2014` if I explicitly use a `WHERE` clause of

```
WHERE [Posting Date] <> '2014-12-31 23:59:59.000')
```

But I need the query to work for any year.  I tried:

```
WHERE (DATEPART(mm, [Posting Date]) <> 12) AND 
      (DATEPART(dd, [Posting Date]) <> 31) AND 
      (DATEPART(hh, [Posting Date]) <> 23) AND 
      (DATEPART(mi, [Posting Date]) <> 59) AND 
      (DATEPART(ss, [Posting Date]) <> 59)
```

But that filtered out everything that was in `December` or had a day of `31` or an hour of `23`, etc...

Is there a simple way to filter a given datetime, but with any year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this:

```
WHERE MONTH([Posting Date]) <> 12 OR
      DAY([Posting Date]) <> 31 OR
      CAST([Posting Date] AS TIME) <> CAST('23:59:59.000' AS TIME)
```

Even more short answer:

```
WHERE YEAR([Posting Date]) <> YEAR(DATEADD(ss, 1, [Posting Date]))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same results as my query that isn't working.

Comment: @Boone, yes there was a mistake, you need `OR`s

Comment: I suspect performance for this will be really bad as the query optimizer won't be able to use any indexes and will have to process each row. A better idea would be to create a table with exclusion dates for the next 50 years (50 rows only) and exclude these from the report, eg with `WHERE [Posting Date] NOT IN ...)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you for that advice.  While my data is relatively small, it was very simple to implement and reduced my execution time from 11 seconds to 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing which you can also do is something like this, which is a slight variation from what you have tried.

```
WHERE 1 = CASE 
        WHEN (
                DATEPART(MONTH, [POSTING DATE]) = 12
                AND DATEPART(DAY, [POSTING DATE]) = 31
                AND DATEPART(HOUR, [POSTING DATE]) = 23
                AND DATEPART(MINUTE, [POSTING DATE]) = 59
                AND DATEPART(SECOND, [POSTING DATE]) = 59
                )
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END
```

In this scenario I just use a `CASE` to identify those rows which have the date the last second of the year and the evaluation of 1/0 does the rest and filters out the unwanted records.