# Filter By date with format 'dd/mm'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have difficulty in syntax query dbms oracle for filtering by date, but i just want filter by date with format (dd/mm). and my data database record is (dd/mm/yyyy). How query to filter by date mm/dd

tablename.fieldname >= '01/01'

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I don't understand how `>=` would be used in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
with s as (
select date '2019-01-01' + level * 15 dt from dual connect by level <= 20)
select s.*
from s
where to_number(to_char(dt, 'mmdd')) > 0501;

DT                 
-------------------
2019-05-16 00:00:00
2019-05-31 00:00:00
2019-06-15 00:00:00
2019-06-30 00:00:00
2019-07-15 00:00:00
2019-07-30 00:00:00
2019-08-14 00:00:00
2019-08-29 00:00:00
2019-09-13 00:00:00
2019-09-28 00:00:00
2019-10-13 00:00:00
2019-10-28 00:00:00

12 rows selected.
```

Comment: Not work master, they still showing  month > 01

     with s as(
select date '2019-01-01' + level * 15 dt from dual connect by level <= 20)
select s.*
from s
where to_number(to_char(dt, 'ddmm')) < 0201;

DT
01/04/2019
01/05/2019

Comment: I am sorry, i have edit your code to ddmm, please look my comment code. master

Comment: i want filter by dd/mm for birthday filter

Comment: @DimasPrayoga you need to filter by mmdd in order to get the results, due to ordering. `'15/12'` is less than `'23/01` despite the 15th of December being later than 23rd of January. You have to sort by the month first, then the day.

Comment: @Boneist i have dufficult for realitation that code

Comment: @DimasPrayoga why? You mean you absolutely cannot pass the parameter as `mmdd`? (If so, you'd have to convert the string into `mmdd` first, which isn't difficult.) Or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this? Though it's not exactly the format you wanted

```
SELECT * from yourTableName 
WHERE EXTRACT(month from yourDateColumn) >= '1'
AND EXTRACT(day from yourDateColumn) >= '1';
```

[Oracle EXTRACT documentaion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639)

Possible related questions:

[Compare only day and month with date field in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510108/compare-only-day-and-month-with-date-field-in-mysql)

[SQL Filter Out Specific Month, Day, and Time for Any Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530869/sql-filter-out-specific-month-day-and-time-for-any-year)